# Global Array not saving a change made to it

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub changePoints(ByVal Name As String, StartPoint As Boolean, Point As Integer)

    Locations(Point).Name = Name

    If StartPoint = True Then
        For i = 0 To 19
            Locations(i).StartPoint = False
        Next
    End If
    Locations(Point).StartPoint = StartPoint
    DrawGraph()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click

    GraphicalPlot.changePoints(PointNameBox.Text, MakeStart.Checked, LoadedPointValue)

End Sub
```

So i have 2 forms. The first form, when clicked with a point selected, brings up the second form with details of the point in an editable textbox. When you click the save button on the second form to save details, the 2nd subroutine above runs, and calls the subroutine in the first form that holds the global variable.

The information passes to the subroutine in the first form correctly. When i check the value of the global array immediately after changing it (right after the line Locations(Point).Name = Name), it says the value has been changed properly.

However, after the subroutine finishes, the global array returns to the value it had before the subroutine was called, and there is no trace of the information i input to the second form.

If it helps, the global array is of a structure:

```
Structure EnteredPoint
    Dim Xcoord As Integer   'Stores X co-ordinate of point
    Dim Ycoord As Integer   'Store Y co-ordinate of point
    Dim Name As String      'Stores name of point, used to check if point is unused
    Dim StartPoint As Boolean   'Checks if the point is the start point
    Dim Selected As Boolean     'Checks if the point is currently being hovered over the mouse
    Dim nextPoint As Integer    'Used to implement a linked list, making deleting and recreating points easier
End Structure
```

The name changing back to what it was shouldn't be possible; the only time my program changes the name outside of initialization (which sets it to "unused", or the number of points that have been created) is here.

I've googled it, showed it to my teacher, and a friend, and we couldn't find anything despite playing with it for hours. Any help would be much appreciated, since this is for my Comp4 coursework!

Edit: added for vbnet3d

```
Sub DrawGraph()
    'Used to draw the current state.
    G = Me.CreateGraphics
    G.Clear(Color.White)    'Sets entire background to white
    Dim placeholder As Integer = 0  'Used to store the current point being checked.
    If UsedLocations > 0 Then   'This part will only run if any points have been made
        Do Until Locations(placeholder).nextPoint = 0   'Loops until all points have been drawn

            If Locations(placeholder).StartPoint = True Then    'will only draw this if it is the starting point
                G.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightBlue, Locations(placeholder).Xcoord - 3, Locations(placeholder).Ycoord - 3, 16, 16)
            End If
            If Locations(placeholder).Selected = True Then      'Will only draw this if it is the currently selected point
                G.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGreen, Locations(placeholder).Xcoord - 3, Locations(placeholder).Ycoord - 3, 16, 16)
            End If
            'Draws the actual Point
            G.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, Locations(placeholder).Xcoord, Locations(placeholder).Ycoord, 10, 10)
            If UsedLocations <= 20 Then
                placeholder = Locations(placeholder).nextPoint  'Gets the next point to be checked.
            End If


        Loop
        If UsedLocations = 20 Then
            If Locations(placeholder).Selected = True Then      'Will only draw this if it is the currently selected point
                G.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGreen, Locations(placeholder).Xcoord - 3, Locations(placeholder).Ycoord - 3, 16, 16)
            End If
            'Draws the actual Point
            G.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, Locations(placeholder).Xcoord, Locations(placeholder).Ycoord, 10, 10)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the Locations array declared?

Comment: Probably has to do with default form references.  What are the form names?

Comment: Locations array is declared at the very top, globally, first line under public class Graphical Plot

Comment: Form names are GraphicalPlot and GraphicsMenu

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the code of DrawGraph()?

Comment: DrawGraph() added to main body

Comment: Use explicit form instances. `GraphicalPlot.changePoints` can too easily refer to the class not the instance you see on screen

Comment: Trying to figure out if i can get that working, haven't used explicit instances very much in the past, so getting it to refer to the correct instance is confusing me a bit :/

Comment: Just a hunch... have you tried using Me.Locations?

Comment: Just tried it, it didn't seem to work, where were you thinking of using it?

Comment: Also worth noting, After trying some console outputs, it seems that before wanting to save the name, it thinks that the name is null, which I'd guess suggests a new instance is made.

Comment: I think using Structure is your culprit... see Chris Dunaway's answer.

Comment: Just tried his answer, no dice :/ The locations(point) being used by the subroutine is null for some reason.

Comment: What is `GraphicalPlot`?  @vbnet3d suggestion is valid.  Try using `Me.changePoints(...)` in the SaveButton click event.

Comment: GraphicalPlot is the class that creates the second form (GraphicsMenu), GraphicsMenu is where the savebutton is located, and calls the changepoints subroutine in GraphicalPlot

Comment: If it would help, i can message you a copy to a dropbox link of all of my code, over skype or something similar.

Comment: @Hellfire If you want to send me a dropbox link, I will check it over.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply, School ended. Add me on skype (hell_fire_omega) and I'll send you the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is being caused by default form references. (See comment by @Plutonix) What this means is that you have a base class instance called "GraphicalPlot" but you also have an active instance of "GraphicalPlot" which is a separate instance. These two classes are identical in form, but do not share in-memory data (one is a model for the other). When you make the following call, it references the model form instead of the active form:

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click

    GraphicalPlot.changePoints(PointNameBox.Text, MakeStart.Checked, LoadedPointValue)

End Sub
```

You need to create a reference to the active form (GraphicalPlot), and pass it to GraphicsMenu using **Me** as the current instance reference. Something along the lines of:

```
GraphicsMenu.Load(Me, PointName, PointNum)
```

And in GraphicsMenu:

```
Dim GP As GraphicalPlot
Public Sub Load(ByVal PlotForm As GraphicalPlot, ByVal Name As String, pointnumber As Integer)

    GP = PlotForm

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a value type (Structure) in your array.  When you access the array element, you are getting a *copy* of the item so your changes are only made on the copy.

You will have to get the EnteredPoint from the array, change the properties as needed and then reassign the point back to the array:

```
Public Sub changePoints(ByVal Name As String, StartPoint As Boolean, Point As Integer)

    Dim pointToChange As EnteredPoint = Locations(Point)

    pointToChange.Name = Name

    If StartPoint = True Then
        For i = 0 To 19
            Dim tmp As EnteredPoint = Locations(i)
            tmp.StartPoint = False
            Locations(i) = tmp
        Next
    End If

    pointToChange.StartPoint = StartPoint
    Locations(Point) = pointToChange

    DrawGraph()
End Sub
```

If you wish to keep your original syntax, then you can change EnteredPoint to a class and it will work as you expect.

Comment: Just tried copy/pasting the edited subroutine you suggested, still no dice :/ After checking what's being used, the Locations(point) being loaded into PointToChange seems to be null.

Comment: @Hellfire - If `Locations` is an array of `EnteredPoint`, which is a structure, it cannot be null because value types cannot be null.  If the integer `Point` points to a valid index in the array, then it cannot be null.  If the integer is invalid, you will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.